# jQuery popup (bpopup) doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, popup, bpopup

I´m trying to implement a multiple popup-function which simply doesn´t work.
I got two kinds of popups to show up. The plugin used is bpopup.

```
// multibind on srate-classes for rating
$(document).ready(function () { 
$(document).on('click', '.SRATE', function() {
    $('#SRATE-div').bPopup({
        closeClass: 'srateBtn',
        modalClose: false,
        escClose: false,
        zIndex: -1
    });
    alert('sollte eigentlich erscheinen');
});

// multibind on brate-classes for rating
$(document).on('click', '.BRATE', function() {
    $('#BRATE-div').bPopup({
        closeClass: 'brateBtn',
        modalClose: false,
        escClose: false,
        zIndex: -1
    });
    alert('sollte eigentlich erscheinen');
});
```

});

The HTML for triggering the function:

```
<img width="24" height="24" src="img/glyphicons_150_rate.png" alt="Inserat ausstehend" class="BRATE" />
```

The id to show up:

```
<div id="BRATE-div">
```

The HTML-stuff reiterates with the SRATE-thing.

With zIndex: 9999 I get the blackout-window appeared with noch content-field in it (it should actually display the BRATE-div thing). Without it nothing happens except the alert() appears. On every click the alert() is fired correctly.

I hope you have some clues. Thanks in advance.